# How to access a token to download a CSV file automatically

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, network-programming, token

The website I'm looking to scrape has a button which asks for dates of the data you want to download as a .csv file. I have automated this process to download this data via python but need to manually get a token each time from the browser under ctrl,shift,i->cookies->request cookies and then copy and paste the token into the python file each time. The problem is the token times out after 1 day and modifying the expiry and/or issue date does not work so I assume this token is being generated by client side javascript.

I have tried using:

```
response = requests.get(www.exampleurl.com)   
print(response.cookies)
```

And I get an empty response.

I've also tried:

```
print(response.headers)
```

But I do not get the cookie or token data at all.

I want to know where I may find the client side javascript which is generating the token so I can copy the algorithm or atleast run this javascript algorithm each time I need a token.

I'm trying to avoid selenium due to it having a 1GB overhead in comparison to the script which would be 10MB.

Comment: "I assume this token is being generated by client side javascript" this is most likely not a correct assumption.

Comment: YOu can search to see if the token is returned with a simple request. Or you could just use Selenium to let the page render and interact that way.